# C++ application send data on serial only when closed

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port

Using this guide/class (http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/CPPWindows) I wrote a little application to send data on the serial port to an Arduino. (This will be added on a larger project later on)

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {

    Serial* SP = new Serial(argv[1]);

    char outcomingData[256];
    int dataLength = 255;
    int sendData;

    while (SP->IsConnected()) {

        strcpy_s(outcomingData, argv[2]);
        sendData = SP->WriteData(outcomingData, dataLength);
        printf("%s", outcomingData);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the data is sent only when I close the application or delete SP through the destructor. How can I fix this? Is there a workaround or another method that I can add to the class?

Comment: I'm assuming you looked around the Arduino site?

Comment: Does the documentation for the `Serial *SP = new Serial(argv[1]);` or  `SP->IsConnected()` specify if it blocks until a handshake or connection has been made?

Comment: Yes, I searched on the forum, but most of the posts are about the communication between Linux and Arduino. I didn't find anything that could help

Comment: @M4rc There isn't really a documentation, just a couple of comments. The only waiting time is at the end of the constructor: "//We wait 2s as the arduino board will be reseting Sleep(ARDUINO_WAIT_TIME);"

Comment: @C.Dennis  Can you place a few `printf`'s before and after each function call to determine which function itself is causing the issue? Incompatible baudrate can be a culprit. it could even be a windows OS issue.

Comment: @M4rc I already tried and everything works fine. The problem is that Arduino gets the data only when I close the program. It's as if the stream is really sent only when I close it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that your data is being cached such that it isn't actually written to your serial device until `CloseHandle` is called in `~Serial`.  You can avoid this caching behavior by specifying `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH` in your call to `CreateFile`, so that the file creation would look something like:

```
//Try to connect to the given port throuh CreateFile
this->hSerial = CreateFile(portName,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH,
        NULL);
```

If that doesn't work, there's also `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`, but that may impose limitations on the alignment of the data you write to the device.

---

If you would like to retain the normal buffering behavior, you could add a `Serial::Flush` method that calls `FlushFileBuffers` to force Windows to write any data it has cached out to the device:

```
void Serial::Flush()
{
    FileFlushBuffers(this->hSerial);
}
```

You would then call `SP->Flush()` after `SP->WriteData(...)` to ensure that Windows' buffers are flushed to the device.  This would allow you to make multiple small writes without having to flush each one, possibly improving performance.

---

As a side note, I would question your use of `new` here.  It doesn't seem like it's really needed, and `SP` could just be constructed locally:

```
Serial SP(argv[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks you very much!! I tryed both solutions and it works perfectly! Can I ask you why I shouldn't use "new" there?

Comment: Using `new` does a dynamic allocation, and requires you `delete` the object later.  If you construct the object locally then it will automatically be deleted when it goes out of scope.  In general it's best to avoid `new` when it's not needed, and to use some sort of smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` when it is needed.